# Aplicativo android em segundo plano

Tags: java, android, sdk

Estou trabalhando no projeto open source *Linphone*,quando o aplicativo é fechado não está funcionando em segundo plano, então se alguém me faz um ligação nesse meio tempo não sou notificado, como posso tratar esse problema?

Comment: Você deve criar um serviço, para seu app, [aqui](http://www.felipesilveira.com.br/2015/03/service-em-android/) tem um tutorial explicando como fazer uma implementação.

Comment: Obrigado @MarcoGiovanni, vou dar uma  olhada nesse tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) é um componente do que pode realizar operações longas e não fornece uma interface do usuário. Outro componente do aplicativo pode iniciar um serviço e ele continuará em execução em **segundo plano** mesmo que o usuário alterne para outra aplicação.

> [...]Além disso, um componente poderá vincular-se a um serviço para
>   interagir com ele e até estabelecer comunicação entre processos (IPC).
>   Por exemplo, um serviço pode lidar com operações de rede, reproduzir
>   música, executar E/S de arquivos, ou interagir com um provedor de
>   conteúdo, tudo a partir do segundo plano.

[Aqui tem](http://www.thiengo.com.br/service-android-entendendo-e-utilizando) um exemplo no qual você pode utilizar.

#### Serviço no manifest.xml

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

A classe [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) fornece uma estrutura simples para a execução de uma operação em um único segmento de segundo plano. Isso permite lidar com operações de longa duração sem afetar a capacidade de resposta da sua interface de usuário.

> Esta é uma subclasse de Service que usa um encadeamento de trabalho
>   para lidar com todas as solicitações de inicialização, uma por vez.
>   Esta é a melhor opção se não quiser que o serviço lide com várias
>   solicitações simultaneamente. Tudo que precisa fazer é implementar
>   onHandleIntent(), que recebe a intenção para cada solicitação de
>   início para que você possa realizar o trabalho de segundo plano.

Para criar um componente `IntentService` para seu aplicativo, definir uma classe que estende *IntentService*, e dentro dela, definir um método que substitui `onHandleIntent()`. Por exemplo:

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();

    }
}
```

Para mais detalhes, verifique a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Comment: O *IntentService* não será o componente mais indicado para o que o AP pretende. Ele é útil para executar uma tarefa e terminar, por exemplo um *download* ou *upload*. No caso da pergunta seria de utilizar um *Service* que ficará sempre rodando à espera de "uma ligação".